# How to batch reverse resolve ip address with host command under linux?

Tags: linux, command-line, dns, batch

I pick up ip addresses from the access log, I want to find out where those IP addresses come from. To do this I use this script:

```
cat /var/log/nginx/access.log |awk '{ print $1}'|sort| uniq -c |sort -n -r | awk '{print $2}'
```

an example output is:

```
1.2.3.4
5.6.7.8
...
```

I can pass the result to `nslookup` with the pipeline `|` command, but the result is not easy readable, so I tried to use the `host` command but the only output is an info how to use the `host` command.

How can I use `host` command to batch resolve ip addresses?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use xargs, it converts input from standard input into arguments to a command.

The option -n limits the arguments to one (delimited by newline), and call host multiple times for each one of them, so you can do:

```
cat /var/log/nginx/access.log |awk '{ print $1}'|sort| uniq -c |sort -n -r | awk '{print $2}' | xargs -n 1 host
```